# Hilbert transform of a bandpass signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a bandpass signal x. I am taking hilbert transform of it.

```
hil = hilbert(x);

f = ?

amp = abs(hil);

figure, plot(f,abs(hil);

phase = angle(hil);

figure, plot(f,angle(hil)
```

Here how to define the frequency axis, so i can get the amplitude graph 's length equal to my bandwidth. My bandwidth is here 40 KHz. Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Hi Gluttton, I am using MATLAB

Comment: In my opinion the http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for such question.

Comment: Thanks Gluttton. I will post there my query.